# Assign Sub to dynamically defined CommandButton

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am trying to define a userform that creates a number of listboxes depending on the user. Within the procedure I define commandbuttons supposed to allow the user to take items from one listbox to another.
The commandbuttons are defined as follows (within a loop - see i below):

```
With .Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", Name:="GroupButton1" & i)
    .Top = 40 * (i - 1) + 10
    .Left = 100
    .Width = 20
    .Height = 10
    .BackColor = RGB(220, 105, 0)
    .Caption = ">>"
    .Font.Size = 8
    .OnClick = "GroupButton1" & i & "_Click"
End With
```

I tried to use .OnClick and .OnAction to assign the corresponding _Click sub with no success. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command button does not have `OnClick` property and that is why it is not working. The way that controls are built manually with the designer is different from how they can be built dynamically.

This problem was really annoying, but happily I eventually solved it, however I would not go this route since it is hard to control the situation and the code is more complex. If you use the worksheet as the basis for your control buttons it is a lot easier to create and assign macros to them, you need to simply use  `.OnAction` property in that case.

so follow these instruction CAREFULLY:

1- create a userform where the buttons and other controls will be built dynamically. In my example its name is `UserForm1`. right click on it, choose `view code` and paste this code exactly.

```
Option Explicit
Dim btnArray() As New Class1

Sub CreateButton()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cmdBtn As MSForms.CommandButton


    i = 1

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set cmdBtn = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "MyButton" & i)
        With cmdBtn
            .Name = "GroupButton1" & i
            .Top = 40 * (i - 1) + 10
            .Left = 100
            .Width = 50 'I changed it
            .Height = 25 'I changed it
            .Caption = ">>"
            .Font.Size = 8
            ReDim Preserve btnArray(1 To i)
            Set btnArray(i).btnEvents = cmdBtn
        End With
    Next


End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call Me.CreateButton
End Sub
```

2- Create a `Class Module` (class module and not regular module), by default its name should be `Class1`. You can change it, but I did not. Paste the following code in that module:

```
Public WithEvents btnEvents As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub btnEvents_click()
    MsgBox "It worked"
End Sub
```

3- Now you can call `UserForm1` different ways. I prefer to explicitly call them from a regular module so create a regular module, its name does not matter, but by default it will be `Module1`, paste this code there and when you run it, everything should work perfectly:

```
Sub main()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I  made a mistake when pasting the piece of code. I actually tried to call the sub, as "GroupButton11_Click" with no success. I updated this in the original question. Thanks!

Comment: what error do you get? error number description etc

Comment: I get Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. Thanks much

Comment: I defined a toy sub just for testing as follows:                                                   Sub GroupButton11_Click()

MsgBox "It's called!"

End Sub (for each)

Comment: I edited the answer, put a lota time, but fortunately it worked, please accept the answer and upvote it if you are happy :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Just one thing. All three buttons are calling the same sub. How would you modify this to have one each?

Comment: for each action you need to write the same thing in class module, if you have 10 different buttons with 10 different actions you need to write the same code with different names 10 times. if your actions are similar you can parametrize it with arguments that you will pass to the class module macros.

Comment: or you can pass some parameters to the class macro and then decide what kind of actions it should perform (instead of message box), you can use `IF ELSEIF` or `SELECT CASE` functions to make it functional and clean